# Select elements within a structural scope

Tags: html, css

**What method of CSS selector should be used to identify elements within a particular scope of the page?**

Here, "scope" refers to an element with an ID; all descendant elements are within its scope.
The purpose of this would be to ensure that the elements within can be named and identified without fear of also selecting unrelated elements. It is the same reason for using packages/namespaces in java/c#

## An Example

My website has a feedback button on every page. When clicked, the feedback container is revealed on the side of the page. Within it are a paragraph of instructions, a textarea, and a submit button. Each of these 3 elements needs a specific style that is not shared amongst each other or the rest of the page.
What convention of IDs and/or classes should I give these elements, and how should my stylesheet select them, so that they maintain their scope and do not overlap with other page elements?
I have conceived of 2 options…

## Option 1: Fully qualified IDs

Child element IDs are prefixed with the ID of their parent.

In this example, the main container would have the ID, `feedback`. The inner elements would have the IDs, `feedbackInstructions`, `feedbackSubmission`, and `feedbackSend` respectively. The CSS would then select each element by ID alone.
I do not want to select by element-type as an descendant of the root (`#feedback textarea` for example) in case I add more elements of that type later on and don’t want them to share a style. I want to be very specific about which element I am selecting.

Pros: naming is clear; unique IDs ensures no overlap with other page elements

Cons: further element nesting requires an ever increasing length of name for the ID (`feedbackInstructionsForUsers`, `feedbackInstructionsForAdmins`, etc.)

```css
#feedback {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#feedbackInstructions {
  color: green;
}

#feedbackInstructionsForUser {
  color: purple;
}

#feedbackInstructionsForAdmin {
  color: violet;
}

#feedbackSubmission {
  color: blue;
}

#feedbackSend {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="feedback">
  <p id="feedbackInstructions">
    Ok, here's what to do...
    <p id="feedbackInstructionsForUser">as a regular user...</p>
    <p id="feedbackInstructionsForAdmin">as an administrator...</p>
  </p>
  <form>
    <textarea id="feedbackSubmission"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="feedbackSend" />
  </form>
</div>

<p id="siteInstructions">
  My ID doesn't conflict with what's in the feedback box
</p>
```

## Option 2: Classes as descendants

Child elements are given descriptive class names. They are selected as descendants of the root.

In this example, the main container still has the ID, `feedback`. However, the inner elements now have class names, `instructions`, `submission`, and `send`. The CSS selectors would look like this, `#feedback .instructions`, `#feedback .submission`, and `#feedback .send`.

Pros: class names do not require a prefix; further nesting does not require elongation of the class name (selected as `#feedback .instructions .forUsers` and `#feedback .instructions .forAdmins`)

Cons: class names are not guaranteed to be unique to the page, and may be affected by other stylesheets (I am working with a team and do not have full control over this); when observing elements separately, class names do not give complete contextual information (instructions for what? Oh, it’s inside the feedback div)

```css
#feedback {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#feedback .instructions {
  color: green;
}

#feedback .instructions .forUser {
  color: purple;
}

#feedback .instructions .forAdmin {
  color: violet;
}

#feedback .submission {
  color: blue;
}

#feedback .send {
  color: orange;
}

.instructions {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="feedback">
  <p class="instructions">
    Ok, here's what to do...
    <p class="forUser">as a regular user...</p>
    <p class="forAdmin">as an administrator...</p>
  </p>
  <form>
    <textarea class="submission"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="send" />
  </form>
</div>

<p class="instructions">
  Opps, my class may conflict with something in the feedback box if I'm not careful
</p>
```

## Conclusion

Is one of these 2 options better than the other? Is there a third solution that is more appropriate to this situation? Is there a better solution to use is general?
By “better”, I mean to say that I am looking for a method that is elegant, maintainable over the long term, and/or is widely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy maintainence, option 1 will be better. You can easily find classes with the developer tools in any case and each elements will be highly customisable. There will be many repetitions of styles in this case.

My suggestion is to mix both options with option 2 being used on common elements found on most pages and option 1 being used on elements that will require customising and is unique compared to other pages.

If many elements share the same style and not commonly touched (store this at the top of css file for easy categorising or you could do by sectioning according to parts of webpages like "banner", "news" etc), you could do

```
element1, element2, element3 {
color:red
}
```

and thereafter customise each elements individually.

```
element 1 {
width:100%
}
element 2{
width:50%;
}
element 3{
width: 10%;
}
```

Example stylesheet:

```
//banner
element1 ,element2, element3 {
background: black;
color: yellow;
}
//end of banner
element1 {
width: 10%;
}
element2 {
margin: 0 auto;
}

//news
newselement1 ,newselement2, newselement3 {
background: transparent;
color: black;
}
//end news

newselement1 {
width: 10%;
}
newselement2 {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is my way of styling. Others can correct me as well so I can learn what others are doing. :)